# php - Compare two array and if an index is identical delete it

Tags: php, arrays, json, compare

How can I delete an array index by comparing it to another array index?

PHP:

```
    $results = array ( array(
            "Name" => $NameUser, 
            "Surname" => $SurnameUser, 
            "MyComment" => $MyComment,
            "VideoPath" => $VideoPath,
            "Reg_Date" => $Reg_Date, 
            "ThumbPath" => $ThumbPath, 
            "UserId" => $UserId
            ));  
    print_r($results[0]); // Array ( [Name] => aaa [Surname] => aaa [MyComment] => aaa [VideoPath] => aaa [Reg_Date] => aaa [ThumbPath] => aaa [UserId] => aaa)

$JSON_List = file_get_contents('test.json');
$arr = json_decode($JSON_List);
print_r(￼$arr[0]); // stdClass Object ( [Name] => aaa [Surname] => aaa [MyComment] => aaa [VideoPath] => aaa [Reg_Date] => aaa [ThumbPath] => aaa [UserId] => aaa )
```

I can see these two indexes are identical, I am using a for loop but it seeks that php are not seeing them as identical.

How can I compare the array properly and if identical remove the identical array index from the list?

PHP:

```
foreach ($arr as $index)  {

    $countIndex++;

    print_r($countIndex);

    if ($arr[$countIndex - 1] == $results[0]) {

        print_r("array is identical \n");
    }else{

        print_r("array is not identical \n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having 2 arrays:

```
$results = array ( array(
        "Name" => '$NameUser', 
        "Surname" => '$SurnameUser', 
        "MyComment" => '$MyComment',
        "VideoPath" => '$VideoPath',
        "Reg_Date" => '$Reg_Date', 
        "ThumbPath" => '$ThumbPath', 
        "UserId" => '$UserId'
    )
);  
// print_r($results[0]); 
//$JSON_List = file_get_contents('test.json');
//$arr = json_decode($JSON_List);
$arr = array(array(//simulate
        "Name" => '$NameUser', 
        "Surname" => '$SurnameUser', 
        "MyComment" => '$MyComment',
        "VideoPath" => '$VideoPath',
        "Reg_Date" => '$Reg_Date', 
        "ThumbPath" => '$ThumbPath', 
        "UserId" => '$UserId'
    ),
    array(
        "Name" => '$NameUser2', 
        "Surname" => '$SurnameUser2', 
        "MyComment" => '$MyComment2',
        "VideoPath" => '$VideoPath2',
        "Reg_Date" => '$Reg_Date2', 
        "ThumbPath" => '$ThumbPath', 
        "UserId" => '$UserId2'
));

//Search identicals
function search_identicals(&$arr,$results){
    $response = array();
    foreach($results as $k=>$value){
        array_walk($arr,function($elem,$key)use($value,&$response,&$arr){
            $resp = array_diff($elem,$value);
            if(empty($resp)){
                unset($arr[$key]);
                array_push($response,$elem);
            }
        });
    }
    return ($response) ? $response : false;
}

$identicals = search_identicals($arr,$results);
var_dump('to delete');
var_dump($identicals);
var_dump('deleted');
var_dump($arr);
```

//You only need this:

```
function search_identicals(&$arr,$results){//&$arr by reference
    foreach($results as $k=>$value){
        array_walk($arr,function($elem,$key)use($value,&$arr){
            $resp = array_diff($elem,$value);//if is identical, return empty
            if(empty($resp)){
                unset($arr[$key]);//remove repeated
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the warning:  array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: I have made it to work and the function deletes the key. However, if I save it back to json file the format its changed to '{"1":{}}' instead of '[{"",""},{"",""}...]

Comment: The problem is if I delete key 1 the array is not up dated and it missing the key 1. "[0] => Array(...)[2] => Array (...)" the new array is missing "[1] => Array(...)"

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to check if two keys are present in two separate arrays is using the `array_intersect_key()` function.

```
$sameKeys = array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_intersect_keys()

Comment: My, bad, spelling mistake, it's array_intersect_key()

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `array_unique( array_merge($arr1, $arr2) );`

OR this:

```
$arr_1 = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
$arr_2 = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```

Comment: i get Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in